# Laravel Eloquent: Save accessor response

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm not sure if this has recently changed or if i've just never noticed before, but the response from an Eloquent Accessor is not retained in anyway, meaning that the accessor method is called every single time. In this particular example this is leading to queries being multiple times unnecessarily. Here is an example:

```
<?php
//Career Model
class Career extends Model {
    public function seasons()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Season', 'career_id');
    }

    pubic function getSeasonsCountAttribute()
    {
        return $this->seasons()->count();
    }
}

//Season Model
class Season extends Model {
}

//Blade Template
@if($career->seasonsCount)
    <div>Seasons Count: {{ $career->seasonsCount }}</div>
@endif
```

From this little bit of code the query will be run twice, because $seasonsCount is accessed twice.

> select count(*) as aggregate from `seasons` where `seasons`.`career_id` = '12316' and `seasons`.`career_id` is not null
>
> select count(*) as aggregate from `seasons` where `seasons`.`career_id` = '12316' and `seasons`.`career_id` is not null

I realise I can avoid this by doing something one of these two:

```
pubic function getSeasonsCountAttribute()
{
    if(is_null($this->seasonsCountCache))
    {
        $this->seasonsCountCache = $this->seasons()->count();
    }

    return $this->seasonsCountCache;
}
```

OR

```
@if($seasonsCount = $career->seasonsCount)
    <div>Seasons Count: {{ $seasonsCount }}</div>
@endif
```

While these will work, I would like to find if there is some way within Laravel to prevent this being accessed each time. It seems like a very odd design decision to require calling the function each time.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem odd to me in the way the query builder works.

It's like you were saying: "it's weird because when I do

```
$careers = Career::all();
$newCareers = Career::all();
```

It fires two queries"

Well of course it does, it's your responsibility to cache data that you already retrieved previously.

Your solution with the `seasonsCountCache` property, seems nice though.